# Create a 3D column chart using asp.net - how to add z axis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am very new to ASP.NET charting tools. I have a data table at hand which contains 10 series (QOL-1 to QOL-10). These 10 items are asked in one questionnaire all together on multiple dates. So for each date, there will be 10 answers collected. I would like to plot a 3D column chart to show the answers for each question on each date, where the X-axis indicates dates that data was collected, Y-axis indicates the answer, and Z-axis indicates the item labels (QOL-1 to QOL-10).

However, I am not sure how to add this Z-axis.

[This is what I have for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8gIZ.png)

And I want to achieve:

[This is what I want to achieve for Z-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyHuU.png)

I also attached my code:

C#:

```
            QoLChart.DataBindCrossTable(qol_data.DefaultView, "label", "Date", "Value", "");
            QoLChart.DataBind();
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].Area3DStyle.IsClustered = false;
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].Area3DStyle.Perspective = Convert.ToInt32(PerspectiveBox.Text.ToString());
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].Area3DStyle.Inclination = Convert.ToInt32(InclinationBox.Text.ToString());
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].Area3DStyle.Rotation = Convert.ToInt32(RotationBox.Text.ToString());
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].Area3DStyle.PointDepth = Convert.ToInt32(PointDepthBox.Text.ToString());
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].Area3DStyle.PointGapDepth = Convert.ToInt32(GapDepthBox.Text.ToString());
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisY.Interval = 1;
            QoLChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45;
```

aspx:

```
<asp:Chart ID="QoLChart" runat="server" Height="800px" Width="1200px" Palette="None" 
PaletteCustomColors="LightSteelBlue; Thistle; Plum; Orchid; MediumOrchid; DarkOrchid; Purple; Indigo">
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea3" BackColor="White">
                <AxisY>
                    <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 12pt" />
                    <MajorGrid LineColor="White" />
                    <MinorGrid LineColor="Blue" />
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX>
                    <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 12pt" />
                    <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="Legend3">
            </asp:Legend>
        </Legends>
    </asp:Chart>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </td>   
    </tr></table>
</asp:Content>
```